# How to setup magento admin to send email to customer when order is cancelled

Tags: magento

I'm using magento 1.5 and I need to send email to customer that their order has been cancelled by the admin. can someone help and show me the steps to do this part in magento admin panel.?

I really need your help. thanks in advance, your response is highly appreciated.

Comment: Is this supported natively by Magento? I think you need to rewrite the order controller to attach a send email function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use an event, to tell if the order was cancelled. I don't know if there is such an even (`sales_order_cancelled` or something like that), otherwise you could try to observe `sales_order_save_after`, and check if the order was cancelled, then send the email.

**==========EDIT===========**

From what I read in http://www.nicksays.co.uk/magento_events_cheat_sheet/, you should use the event `order_cancel_after`. Check `app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Order.php` to see how it's called.